# separation lines on weekstart when GetHorizAxis.Increment := DateTimeStep[dtOneWeek]

Tags: delphi, teechart

I use D2007 and Teechart v7.10 standard
I want to show the data per week.
I set

```
Series1.GetHorizAxis.Increment := DateTimeStep[dtOneWeek];
```

and

```
chart1.TopAxis.minimum = //a Monday's date
```

The problem is that the vertical separation lines and their dates aren't on 
Mondays.
Is any way to force these marks to be at the start of week ?
thanks in advance

Using TGantSeries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried with the actual version (v2013.09) and I always get a bottom axis with labels on Mondays using the following simple example:

```
uses GanttCh;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Chart1.View3D:=false;
  Chart1.Legend.Visible:=false;

  Chart1.AddSeries(TGanttSeries).FillSampleValues;

  with Chart1.Axes.Bottom do
  begin
    LabelsAngle:=90;
    Increment:=DateTimeStep[dtOneWeek];
    DateTimeFormat:='ddd dd/mm/yyyy';
  end;
end;
```

However, I see in TeeChart v7 the code above shows different weekdays in the labels depending on the values in the series. Then, the only solution I can think on is to use custom labels. Ie:

```
uses GanttCh;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var tmpDate: TDateTime;
begin
  Chart1.View3D:=false;
  Chart1.Legend.Visible:=false;

  Chart1.AddSeries(TGanttSeries).FillSampleValues;

  Chart1.MarginBottom:=15;
  with Chart1.Axes.Bottom do
  begin
    LabelsAngle:=90;
    //Increment:=DateTimeStep[dtOneWeek]; //this won't take effect with custom labels
    DateTimeFormat:='ddd dd/mm/yyyy';

    tmpDate:=(Chart1[0] as TGanttSeries).StartValues.MinValue;
    while DayOfWeek(tmpDate) <> 2 do
      tmpDate:=tmpDate+1;

    Items.Clear;
    repeat
      Items.Add(tmpDate);
      tmpDate:=tmpDate+7;
    until tmpDate>=(Chart1[0] as TGanttSeries).EndValues.MaxValue;
  end;
end;
```

Note in the solution above there's no antioverlap control for the axis labels

Comment: thanks for your reply, i forgot to mention that my chart is of type GANTT. So the Xvalues haven't sequential dates to use your suggestion. Regardless of the first data date, the separation line is at Thurstdays.

Comment: I've just edit my answer adapting it to TGanttSeries. I've also edited your question with this key info...

Comment: Yes, it works ! and overlaping isn't a problem for my case. Thank you